# como puedo cambiar datos que se almacenan en el localStorage?

Tags: javascript, html, html5, ecmascript-6, local-storage

estoy tratando de mejorar el código de mi primer proyecto, un `to do list` y lo que quiero hacer es guardar los items en el `localStorage`, de forma que al refrescar el navegador, estos no se borren o reinicien, pero sobre todo que también se guarden los items chequeados o que al eliminar los items no vuelvan a aparecer al refrescar la pagina. Yo en cada item tengo tres botones:

- el botón para completar o chequear el item: `checkButton`
- el botón para editar las tareas: `editButton`
- el botón para eliminar las tareas: `trashButton`

Guardo los datos en una lista de objetos que contienen un `único id`, `nombre del item` (donde almaceno el valor del input) y el valor del boton que chequea los items que se almacena en `completed` ( que seria `checkButton.value`, valor que me sirve para saber si el item esta completado o chequeado).

El problema, como mencione antes, es que si se guarda el item en el `localStorage` pero no los cambios que hago en el mismo. Por ejemplo digamos que pongo un item en la pagina, este se guarda en el localStorage pero imaginemos que después edito su tarea, la elimino o la marco como terminada pero al refrescar la pagina esos cambios que hice no se guardan.

Intente remover los datos del localStorage y volverlos a subir cada vez que quisiera editar los valores pero no funciono.

Por favor si me explican que es lo que sucede y también agradecería si me dicen si a simple vista mi código es legible y si se entiende o mejor dicho si es un código limpio

```js
"use strict"
//date function
const dateElement= document.getElementById("date");
const options= {
    weekday:"long",
    month:"short",
    day:"numeric"
}
const today= new Date();

dateElement.innerHTML= today.toLocaleDateString("en-US",options);

const list= document.getElementById("list");
const input= document.getElementById("input");
const normalButton= document.getElementById("normal");
const finishedTask= document.getElementById("done");
const unfinishedTask= document.getElementById("not-done");
const refreshBtn = document.getElementById("refresh-btn");
const failBox = document.getElementById("fail");
const closeBtn = document.getElementById("close-btn");

document.addEventListener("keyup",(event)=>{ if(event.keyCode === 13) addToDo() });

let lists = [];
// Obtener desde localStorage al cargar todo el DOM
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    lists = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("item.list")) || [];
    // Agregar en HTML los elementos encontrados
    lists.forEach((item) => addToDo(item));
});

function addToDo(fromList){
    

    refreshBtn.addEventListener("click",() => refreshPage());

    event.preventDefault();

    let itemValue= (fromList) ? fromList.name : input.value;
    

    function failAlert(){
        failBox.style.display = "block";
        closeBtn.addEventListener("click", ()=> failBox.style.display = "none")
    }

    if(itemValue === "" || itemValue === null) return failAlert();
    
    const itemNew= document.createElement("li");
    const deleteButton= document.createElement("button");
    const para = document.createElement("p");
    const editButton= document.createElement("button");
    const checkButton= document.createElement("button");
    const buttonsContainer= document.createElement("div");

    itemNew.appendChild(buttonsContainer);
    buttonsContainer.classList.add("buttons");
    
    //creating text
    para.classList.add("text");
    const text= document.createTextNode(itemValue);
    para.appendChild(text);
    
    //item
    itemNew.classList.add("item");
    itemNew.appendChild(checkButton);           
    itemNew.appendChild(para);
    list.appendChild(itemNew);

    //check-buttton
    checkButton.classList.add("checkbox");
    checkButton.innerHTML = `<i class="far fa-circle fa-lg"></i>`
    checkButton.value= "not-checked";

    //edit-button
    editButton.classList.add("edit");
    editButton.innerHTML = `<i class="far fa-edit"></i>`
    buttonsContainer.appendChild(editButton);
    
    //delete-button
    deleteButton.classList.add("delete");
    deleteButton.innerHTML = `<i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>`
    buttonsContainer.appendChild(deleteButton);
    
 
    //ACA ES DONDE CHEQUELO LOS ITEMS
    checkButton.addEventListener("click",() =>{
        //SI EL VALOR DEL CHECKBUTTON NO ESTA CHEQUEADO EJECUTA LA FUNCION COMPLETEDTASK()
        checkButton.value ==="not-checked" ? completedTask(): incompletedTask();
        
        function completedTask() {
            checkButton.setAttribute("value","checked");
            checkButton.innerHTML = `<i class="far fa-check-circle fa-lg"></i>`
        } 
        function incompletedTask() {
            checkButton.setAttribute("value","not-checked");
            checkButton.innerHTML = `<i class="far fa-circle fa-lg"></i>`
        }
        
        para.classList.toggle("completed");
    });

    //ACA YO ES DONDE EDITO LAS TAREAS
    editButton.addEventListener("click",()=>{
            para.innerHTML = `<div class=".edit-container" id = "edit-container"></div>`;
            let editContainer = document.getElementById("edit-container")
            let editInput = document.createElement("input");
            let submitEdit = document.createElement("button");

            editInput.classList.add("edit-input");
            submitEdit.classList.add("submit-edit");

            submitEdit.innerHTML = `<i class="fas fa-plus-circle fa-lg"></i>`

            editContainer.appendChild(editInput);
            editContainer.appendChild(submitEdit);

            submitEdit.addEventListener("click",() => para.innerHTML = editInput.value);

        }
    );

    //ACA ELIMINO LA TAREA
    deleteButton.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
        list.removeChild(itemNew);
    }  );
         
    //normal button
    normalButton.addEventListener("click", ()=> itemNew.setAttribute("style","display:block") );

    //finished-task button
    finishedTask.addEventListener("click",()=>{
        checkButton.value==="checked" ? itemNew.setAttribute("style","display:block")
        :itemNew.setAttribute("style","display:none");
    });

    //unfinished-task button
    unfinishedTask.addEventListener("click",()=>{
        checkButton.value==="not-checked" ? itemNew.setAttribute("style","display:block")
        :itemNew.setAttribute("style","display:none");
    });

    let data = createDataList(itemValue, checkButton.value);

    if(!fromList) {
        lists.push(data);
        save();
    }

    function save(){  
        localStorage.setItem("item.list", JSON.stringify(lists));
    }

    function createDataList(name, completed){
        return {id: Date.now(), name: name, completed: completed};
    }

    input.value = "";
}

function refreshPage(){
        localStorage.clear();
        location.reload();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed:300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/09faf5376a.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <title>To Do List</title>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">

        <div class="header">
           
            <i class="fas fa-sync-alt" id="refresh-btn"></i>
         
            <div class="title-container">
                <h1 class="title">To Do List App</h1>
                <h2 class="ferre">By Fxrree</h2>
            </div>
            
            <div class="date" id="date"></div>
            
            <div class="functionalities">
                <button id="normal" class="normal">NORMAL</button>
                <button id="done" class="done">DONE</button>
                <button id="not-done" class="not-done">NOT-DONE</button>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="fail" id="fail">
            <i class="fas fa-times-circle" style="color: #fff;" id="close-btn"></i>

            <p class="failed-text">Please type a valid to do</p>
        </div>

        <div class="content">
            <ul id="list" class="list"></ul>
        </div>

        <div class="add-item">
            <input type="text" class="input" id="input" placeholder="Add something to do">
            <i class="fas fa-plus-circle fa-lg" id="button" onclick="addToDo()"></i>
        </div>

    </div>
    <script src="app.js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Solo debes recuperarlos en una variable y luego simplemente añades los valores que quieres y los vuelves a guardar bajo la misma clave en local storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes modifiar la data de localStorage también en cada evento del botón editar y checked de cada correspondiente item.
Por ejemplo en esta línea:

```
submitEdit.addEventListener("click",() => para.innerHTML = editInput.value);
```

Ahí sólo estás mostrando el nuevo valor en el elemento, pero no modificas la data de localStorage.
Lo que debes hacer ahí es detectar cual es el item en localStorage correspondiente al item del DOM que estas modificando para luego generar un nuevo array con el item editado y luego guardarlo en localStorage. Sin embargo, así como está tu código deberás hacer varias modificaciones. 
Lo más rápido sería añadir un "data-id" a los "li.item" con el valor del id de los items de tu localStorage (que es el "new Date()" que usas). De esta forma dentro del manejador del evento podrías hacer algo como esto:

```
submitEdit.addEventListener("click",() => {
   para.innerHTML = editInput.value
   const id = itemNew.dataset.id
   const dataLS = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('item.list'))
   const itemAModificar = dataLS.find(item=>item.id === id)
   itemAModificar.name = editInput.value
   localStorage.setItem('item.list', JSON.stringify(dataLS))
});
```

Esta idea en sí funcionaría. Recuerda que también debes hacer algo similar con el botón de checked.

Adicionalmente a esto te sugeriría lo siguiente:

- Si sólo usarás esa data en localStorage entonces podrías usar varios campos en localStorage. Es decir, que todo no esté en "item.list", sino que cada item sea un elemento independiente en localStorage. Los beneficios de esto es el rendimiento y legibilidad en el código porque ya no tendrás que extraer toda la data, convertir en un array, buscar en el array, modificar ese array, convertir todo esto en JSON y luego guardar todo otra vez en localStorage, sino sólo harías algo como esto:

```
const updateItem = ID => {
   const itemStr = localStorage.getItem(ID)
   const itemData = JSON.parse(itemStr)
   itemData.name = nuevoNombre
   const nuevoItemStr = JSON.stringify(itemData)
   localStorage.setItem(ID, nuevoItemStr)
}

submitEdit.addEventListener("click",() => {
   para.innerHTML = editInput.value
   const id = itemNew.dataset.id
   updateItem(id)
});
```

De esta forma se usará muchos menos procesos en cada edición.

- ¡No trates de crear una sóla función que haga de todo! Divide responsabilidades y trátalas por separado, si ves que es muy complejo y extenso divídelo aun más. Así es mucho más fácil saber que está pasando en cada momento y se podrá entender el código a la primera leída.
- Para hacer lo anterior con éxito debes conceptuar tus elementos y sus estilos y funcionalidades relacionadas como "componentes" e identificar requerimientos como estos:

  - Una función para crear el componente "Item".
  - Una funcion para crear el sub-componente "Valor".

    - Sólo mostrará el valora actualizado con los estilos específicos.
  - Una función para crear el sub-componente "Editar".

    - Ejecuta la funcionalidad de edición del usuario y logra las actualizaciones con el localStorage.
  - Una función para crear el sub-componente "Checked".

    - Similar al anterior, pero siempre es recomendable tenerlo por separado.
  - Una función para crear el sub-componente "Eliminar".

    - Elimina el componente item del DOM y remueve su correspondiente en el localStorage.

... Este modo puedes llevarlo al resto de tus funcionalidades. Recuerda que es mejor mantener el orden y la legibilidad que un código super abstracto y compacto.

- El problema que tratas de resolver es clásico. Tener los datos centralizados y mantenerlo consistente con el resto de la aplicación. Cuando avances en el desarrollo te recomendaria que revises React y Redux, no obligando a que desarrolles con eso, pero que sí entiendas su filosofía y el porqué lo hacen.

Happy code!

Comment: Hola muchas gracias por tu explicación y tus consejos.

Comment: Una pregunta mas recomendarias que entonces en vez de guardar todos los items dentro de "list" (que seria un array), guarde a cada item por separado en el localStorage.

Comment: Para ese caso en concreto: sí. Para aplicaciones grandes es casi inevitable centralizar sub-modelos de datos. 
Es raro ver un montón de items en localStorage que daría la impresión que es mala práctica, pero si está bien modularizado en el código el consumo y modificación del localStorage entonces nada te impide hacerlo. Además así evitas el proceso que te mencioné en la respuesta. De todas formas si quieres obtener en cierto momento toda la data de localStorage sólo haces lo siguiente:
const dataTotal = localStorage; 
o 
const dataTotal = {...localStorage};
Saludos. (Y)